# Second eigenvalue for the Steklov eigenvalue problem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the Steklov eigenvalueproblem on the ball $B_r\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $r$
\begin{align*}
\Delta \varphi &= 0~~~~~\text{in    } ~~~B_r \\
\partial_\nu \varphi &= \lambda \varphi ~~~\text{auf } \partial B_r.
\end{align*}
It is well know that the spectrum can be arranged via
$$
0=\lambda_0 < \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 \leq \dots \to \infty.
$$
I now know that we have
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{r}.
$$
My question know is, if $\lambda_2$ is known for the ball $B_r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Example $1.3.2$ of this paper [Spectral Geometry of the Steklov Problem](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~iossif/steklov_spectral_geometry.pdf) by Girouard and Polterovich.